# Reading excel file throws a COMException

Tags: c#, excel, file, interop

I am trying to read from an EXCEL file and display what i get.

Here is my Excel Class.

```
class Excel
    {
        private string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
         Workbook workbook;
         Worksheet worksheet;

        public Excel(string path, int sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheet];
        }

        public string ReadCell(int row, int column)
        {
            row++;
            column++;

            if (worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value2 != null)
            {
                return worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value2;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how i call it

```
string pathToFile = @"K:\hours\tracking.xlsx";
Excel excel = new Excel(pathToFile, 1);
MessageBox.Show(excel.ReadCell(0, 0));
```

Here is my exception

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>     HResult=0x80040154
>     Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>      at working_hours.Excel..ctor(String path, Int32 sheet) in K:\programming\visual_studio_projects\working_hours\working_hours\working_hours\Excel.cs:line 14
>      at working_hours.Program.Main(String[] args) in K:\programming\visual_studio_projects\working_hours\working_hours\working_hours\Program.cs:line 31

I Chcked if the path is correct and it is.

I think it may have to do with the References that i just implemented, but im not quite Sure.

I added

`System.Windows.Forms.dll`
and
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use interop to parse excel.

Comment: Any other suggestion, and why ?

Comment: Cause you don't need it anymore. `.xlsx` files now use openXML, an open and standard format, and you can parse them easily. I've used `EPPlus` recently, but there is a ton of library out there (LinqToExcel, ClosedXML, ...)

Comment: COM interop is something you would want to stay as far as possible. Trust me. Unless you are c++ person and loves debugging mem leak, seg fault, access violation, heap corruption ect using windbg

Comment: I usually don't like it when someone says not to do what you're trying to do instead of helping you do it. But in this case I have to agree. Interop is a cesspool of misery, and when you solve this problem it will reward you with evil. It will curse you for generations. If you switch to EPPlus you solve this problem and prevent a bunch of other ones.